# Bitmap not aligned properly in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, formatting, android-relativelayout

In my code, I re-size a bitmap and then use the bitmap in my code using `imageView.setImageBitmap()`. However, for some reason the image will not be at the top of the layout, rather it ends up in the center of the screen ( http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/ssbluepic.png/ )

Here is the code for my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <!--   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>


    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2"></TextView>  -->



    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

(the two `TextViews` are commented out).

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to add the parameters for the position of the image in the layout programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your XML-file and the following java code. The positioning of the image at the top works fine. Probably something wrong with your java code.

```
package com.androidplant.RelLayoutTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RelLayoutTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 18, 18, true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the wrong width/height paremeters in the createScaledBitmap method. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your image is at the top but getting rescaled or includes space in the image? Take a look at ImageView.ScaleType.

Comment: I tried using fitStart, and it works, until I uncomment the textViews, then only they show up (overlapping).

Comment: That's because they're both alignParentTop. Not sure what you're trying to do now but take a look at the positioning options for RelativeLayout (if that's the layout class you really want).